# aurelia validation property expression help needed

Tags: validation, properties, aurelia

I am trying to match a single aurelia validation to a bunch of properties in a form.  E.g. every field with a property name of `ssid` in an array of objects that map to rows in a table.  The validation docs say that the ensure clauses can have a `property expression` which sounds like what I need.  I'm using the validation from

`{ValidationRules, ValidationController} from 'aurelia-validation';`

I've got validation working for a single property using

`ValidationRules.ensure('apPwd').displayName('XY AP Password').maxLength(32).minLength(8).on(this);`

where apPwd is the property expression.

But I can't find any spec for property expressions.  Most examples in the aurelia docs just show a single property name.  The most complicated I've seen are things piped together with `|` or `&` (whatever that is).

Can anyone point me to a spec or help with my specific problem?  Or maybe I should just ditch this package and roll my own code?

Answer (score 0):

I think this can help you out:

This is validate.ts

```
import { autoinject } from 'aurelia-framework';
import { ValidationRules, ValidationController } from 'aurelia-validation';

@autoinject
export class Validate {
    numberField: number;

    controller: any;

    constructor (
        private validationController: ValidationController
    ) {
        this.controller = validationController;

        ValidationRules.customRule(
            'nummer',
                (value, obj, min, max) => {
                    let numberValue: number = parseInt(value);
                    return value === null || value === undefined || Number.isInteger(nummer) && nummer >= min && nummer <= max;
                },
                `\${$displayName} must be an integer between \${$config.min} and \${$config.max}.`,
                (min, max) => ({ min, max })
            );

        ValidationRules
            .ensure((m: this) => m.numberField)
                .required()
                .withMessage('Rutan får inte vara tom.')
                .satisfiesRule('nummer', 1, 100)
                /*.satisfies((value: any, object?: any) => {
                    console.log(value);
                    if (value >= 1 && value <= 100) {
                        return true;
                    }
                    else {
                        return false;
                    }
                })
                .withMessage(`The number must be between  - 100.`)*/
            .ensure((m: this) => m.numberField).required()
            .on(this);
    }

    submit(): void {
        this.executeValidation();
    }

    executeValidation(): void {
        this.controller.validate()
        .then(errors => {
            if (errors.length === 0) {
                console.log('all good!');
            } else {
                console.log('all errors!');
            }
        });
    }

}
```

And this is validate.pug (in my case, but you can use a html page if you like)

```
template
    section.au-animate
        h2 Validate

        form(role="form")
            .form-group
                label Number
                input#meetingSubject.form-control(type="text" value.bind="numberField & validate")

            button.btn.btn-lg.btn-primary(click.delegate='submit()') Validate
        div
            h3 ${'latestValidationResult'}
            ul(if.bind='controller.errors.length')
                li(repeat.for='error of controller.errors') ${error.message}
```

Comment: Surprisingly I think I understand everything you've shown with the exception of `.ensure(m => m.numberField)`.  Is that function what the aurelia docs call a `property expression`?  The meaning of that function eludes me.  When is it called and why?  And a pointer to docs for that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understood your question, but I think you're looking for `ensureObject`:

```
ValidationRules
  .ensureObject()
    .satisfies(obj => {
       return obj.property1 === 'test' && obj.property2.indexOf('test2') !== -1
    })
    .withMessage('Some error message.')
  .on(this);
```

Comment: I did a search on `ensureObject` in the aurelia docs and found nothing.  Can you tell where to find out about it?  Maybe you could just explain what `obj` refers to.  How do I get `obj` to be tested for each object in an array, like each `prop` property in `this.rows = [{prop:1},{prop:2}]`?

Comment: You can find the docs at http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/validation/latest/validation-basics/8. If you want to validate each property in an array, just iterate over the array and return false if one the values does not meet the criteria

Comment: `ensureObject` isn't in search results from that docs link either.  Also, this code doesn't produce any output no matter how much I change the form `ValidationRules.ensureObject().satisfies(obj => console.log(obj)).on(this);`.  I guess I'll just keep hacking at it.

Comment: you must returning true or false. `ValidationRules.ensureObject().satisfies(obj => obj.property.length > 10).on(this)`